# How to pass parameters to the .properties file through mvn package

Tags: java, maven

I'd like to ask to help me figuring the issue out below

I have a problem. I need to pass params to the properties file through mvn package. I have following structure

bld.properties (this file is located into src/main/resources)

```
app.vrsn=1.0.0.${prj.build.number}
app.rvsn.nmbr=${prj.build.commit}
```

pom.xml

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

So when I run mvn package -Dprj.build.number=1 -Dprj.build.commit=2 the file bld.properties has the same look such as

```
app.vrsn=1.0.0.${prj.build.number}
app.rvsn.nmbr=${prj.build.commit}
```

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**
Problem was in the following dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Have you checked their content in `target/classes` ?

Comment: Which `bld.properties` file, the one in `src/main/resources` or the one in `target/classes` ? Maven doesn't modify files inside of `src/` as a general rule.

Comment: Do you mean that I shoudn't try to update properties and generate properties file instead?

Comment: My main is to have a properties file which will have parameters from maven command line arguments

Comment: yes. sure I checked target/classes/bld.properties

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to define resources with filtering in your pom.

See this page for all details: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>